# How to enable WebStorm/PhpStorm/IntelliJ IDE to recognize module.exports type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, phpstorm, node-modules

I'm not able to let my IDE know the return type of a module function. Assuming a simple node module like this:

```
function test() {
    return Promise.resolve("test");
}

module.exports = test;
```

Now using the module like this:

```
let test = require("./test");
test().then(text => {
    console.log(text); // prints "test" to console
});
```

But PhpStorm is always complain about `then` function:

> Unresolved function or method then()

I even tried to add a JSDoc to the `test()` function like this:

```
/**
 * test
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function test() {
    return Promise.resolve("test");
}
```

Nothing helps. Is there anything I did wrong or another way to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug, please follow [WEB-24161](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24161) for updates

Comment: Thank you for the informations. Another Bug on the list. :(